# Creating a Maven Project Programmatically Runtime

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

I have created a number of java classes using sun code model library. Now, I would like to create a maven project add those classes and upload it to a Nexus Sonatype Internal Maven Repository. Does anyone know how to create a maven project programmatically. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil: I could find anything usable or a good example so far? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Nope, I don't even know the first thing about Maven. Just trying to get more info for the next person who does!

Comment: You will have to create a pom.xml template and order your sources according to Maven guidelines. Afaik there is no library which does this for you on the fly.

Comment: @UweAllner Thats what I figured. Thank you anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not really programmatically, but maven archetype can generate a project squeleton for you:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} 
   -DartifactId={project-name} 
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
```

You can also run simply :

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

And choose an archetype from the list displayed.

Once done, you can put your java file in src/main/java.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html