# Create maven multi module programmatically

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I have a requirement to create maven project on the fly with dynamic modules depends on user's selection (similar to https://start.spring.io/, but not add as dependency, instead, create N sub-modules). Can someone advise me how to invoke maven archetype programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following the Stackoverflow posts :

- @see [Generate Maven archetype from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541124/generate-maven-archetype-from-java-code)
- @see [Creating a Maven Project Programmatically Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721426/creating-a-maven-project-programmatically-runtime)

You have since some years a Maven plugin to do that task :

- @see https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html

Finally, you can call a Runtime task to execute a command line for your Operating System :

- @see https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/how-to-create-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-command